# SQLite sum integer by dates

Tags: sqlite, date, sum

I have a table named Test

```
"Type" "Value" "Entered"
"O" "40090" "2018-02-01 13:37:00"
"L" "23830" "2018-02-01 10:21:00"
"L" "87140" "2018-02-01 15:26:00"
"L" "63030" "2018-02-01 4:55:00"
"L" "73090" "2018-02-02 12:32:00"
"O" "12320" "2018-02-02 13:0:00"
```

I try to get daily sums by type on each day with following SQL:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Entered) as "Date", sum(Value) as "Sum"
from Test
where Type="O"
group by "Date"
```

but I get NULL instead of 2018-02-02

On bigger set of data, one line from each day gets added to this "NULL date"

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have `"O" "12320" "2018-02-02 13:0:00` instead of `"O" "12320" "2018-02-02 13:00:00` i.e. you should have  **`13:00:00`** not **`13:0:00`** (0 missing from hour).

---

> On bigger set of data, one line from each day gets added to this "NULL
>   date"

You could detect these using `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE entered LIKE '%:_:%';`.

If you're lucky and all the rows are because of an omitted 0 and there is a single 0, you could use the following to correct the rows :-

```
UPDATE Test SET entered = replace(entered,':0:',':00:') WHERE entered LIKE '%:_:%' ;
```

However, if the other rows are incorrect in another way e.g. say you have ***13:1:00*** then the fix would be more complicated as the **1** because it could be that the actual value could be either ***13:01:00*** or ***13:10:00***.